# Where can I find and overview of my rejected suggested edits?

Tags: feature-request

Whenever I try to edit a question I now get this warning:

**Warning! Some of your previous edits were rejected. Please review your recently-rejected edits before continuing. Too many rejected edits may cause your editing privileges to be suspended.**

There is a link in the error message to https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions but on that page there is no info to be found on whether my edits were accepted or rejected. The only way of figuring it out is to click on every individual edit... but there are too many and checking all of them would be a very tedious job.

Wouldn't it be better if that overview page shows whether edits were accepted or rejected without having to click them?

Comment: you could try a query like [THIS ONE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/241907) to get a list of all your rejected suggested edits

Comment: @cVplZ  not really, as there is no real solution

Comment: @vba4all I didn't know you could run queries... while it is a faster way of finding the ones rejected, it still requires more work than it would when the accepted/rejected status would just show on the overview page.  I did post this question as a feature request as I'm convinced I'm not the first one to run into this problem.

Comment: I just checked out the results of that query and in no way it helps to find the rejected edits... the title is empty and searching by text would be impossible.

Comment: @Jongware  It seems to be a duplicate, but the problem never got addressed... and I'm still convinced this should have been implemented.  There are workarounds but the query one is no help at all and that script... I would have to figure out how user scripts work.

Comment: No response so far on the user script, but the suggested query http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/45755/my-rejected-edits works.

Comment: That query is at least usable... thanks!