# "All Activity" and "Responses" show `Oops! Something Bad Happened!`

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

Clicking on `All Activity` tab loads: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11509478/howaboutsynergy?tab=activity
redirects to:
https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/11509478/howaboutsynergy
and thus shows:

```
Oops! Something Bad Happened!

We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.

It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.

Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.

Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them.

It’s not strictly necessary, but if you’d like to give us additional information about this error, do so at our feedback site, https://meta.stackoverflow.com.
```

(the same is shown for `Responses` https://stackoverflow.com/users/11509478/howaboutsynergy?tab=responses )

though the following works:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions
and
https://stackoverflow.com/users/11509478/howaboutsynergy?tab=activity&sort=suggestions
found thanks to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275952/11509478) question.

Note that after using the above working links, something remembers the sub-tab selection for `All Activity` (eg. `Suggestions` for example) and thus doesn't "oops" anymore when trying to reload `All Activity` again(either by clicking it or by browser reload page button) while on the same page(important).

But clicking the sub-tab `All` has no effect. Thus the "oops" must be happening only when `All Activity` is opened and sub-tab `All` is the one that it wants to open(which is the default).

Opening the profile in a new tab is a way to reset the remembered sub-tab selection.

Other non-working sub-tabs (ie. the current sub-tab isn't changed when clicking on any of these sub-tabs): `Posts`, `Badges`, `Comments`, `Revisions`
Working sub-tabs: `Accepts`, `Reviews`, `Suggestions`.

Comment: @PikachutheWatermelonWizard Shouldn't really matter for server-side problems.

Comment: "All actions", "Responses" and "Votes" stopped working, only on the main site, not on meta.

Comment: Works for my "All actions" tab, not yours.  I can hear the error log exploding.

Comment: I see this on any browser, and OS (currently on Chrome for iOS). Work-around: switch to the mobile view (with the link in the footer). The mobile view versions don’t explode.

Comment: The two you mentioned work fine for me, but "Votes" is broken (Firefox on macOS Mojave, if it matters).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fix for this [has just been rolled out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328452/135201).