# "All actions" tab broken yet again

Tags: bug, profile-page

As has happened [many](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385255/all-activity-and-responses-show-oops-something-bad-happened) [times](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398964/all-actions-tab-broken) [before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408548/activity-tab-broken-again), [my "all actions" profile tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112-supports-monica?tab=activity) fails to load. Attempting to load that tab hangs for a while, then displays an "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" error page.

Comment: Happening intermittently with my all actions tab as well. Had [previously reported](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405704/all-actions-in-my-activity-fails-to-load) it

Comment: It is Friday, for SQL Server weekend already started. It is taking it easy.

Comment: Well, this is just great. Who are we going to get to fix it now that Taryn is gone?

Comment: Mine was broken but now works